# GLSL OpenGL Polygons not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to use OpenGL shaders to draw a simple triangle. I have tried to split up the code into separate methods inside one overarching rendering class, however, I cannot seem to get my triangle to render on the screen. This is my compileShaders() method which compiles and loads my shader source code:

```
static const GLchar* vertexShaderSource[] = {
    "#version 430 core                          \n"
    "in vec4 vPosition;                         \n"
    "in vec4 vColor;                            \n"
    "out vec4 color;                            \n"
    "                                           \n"
    "void main() {                              \n"
    "   color = vColor;                         \n"
    "   gl_Position = vPosition;                \n"
    "}                                          \n"
};

GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, vertexShaderSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
glLinkProgram(program);

glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

return program;
```

In a different method I am calling glewInit(), compileShaders() and am then setting up the vertex array and vertex buffer objects. In this method triangleVertices[] and triangleColors[] are two arrays containing the position (x,y,z) and colour values (r,g,b,a) for each vertex the triangle.

```
glewInit();
renderingProgram = compileShaders();

glEnable(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numberOfVertices*7*sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, numberOfVertices*3*sizeof(GLfloat), triangleVertices);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numberOfVertices*3*sizeof(GLfloat), numberOfVertices*4*sizeof(GLfloat), triangleColors);

GLuint vpos = glGetAttribLocation(renderingProgram, "vPosition"); 
glVertexAttribPointer(vpos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 

GLuint cpos = glGetAttribLocation(renderingProgram, "vColor");
glVertexAttribPointer(cpos, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(numberOfVertices*3*sizeof(GLfloat)));   

glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(cpos);
```

Finally my render() method in which I try and draw the Triangle loaded into the Array Buffer:

```
const GLfloat color[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

glUseProgram(renderingProgram);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
SwapBuffers(hDC_);
```

I am rendering to a Win32 window which is setup in a different class. After rendering I can see a blue screen, so it appears as if the `glClearBufferfv` call is working correctly. However my triangle is nowhere to be seen. If I change the rendering mode to `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1)` I see one white pixel in the middle of the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but doesnt OpenGL 3.x require a fragment shader as well, as part of your shader program?
Also, do post the vertex buffer code. You aren't culling or rendering  to a ultra small viewport, right?

Comment: Have you examined the return value of `glLinkProgram(program);`? I'm afraid this would fail since you didn't provide a fragment shader. Also your vertex shader source looks weird.

Comment: Since you're just starting out, I'd suggest you look at:
http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tutorial%2001.html

There's some wonderful code and framework there, and you can reuse that code (compiling, linking shaders and printing errors..etc)

Comment: I found my shaders weren't compiling using `version 440 core`. Once I changed to `version 330 core` they compiled correctly. Adding a fragment shader solved the rendering problem. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need a fragment shader too, e.g.,

```
#version 430

in vec4 color;
out vec4 frag_rgba; // default index (0) (glFragBindDataLocation)

void main (void) {
    frag_rgba = color;
}
```

Attach this shader to the program along with the vertex shader prior to linking. You can [detach](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDetachShader.xml) the shaders from the program after linking. You might also consider using [explicit attribute indices](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) in the vertex shader.

Comment: I added a fragment shader and that seemed to fix the problem. Also it looks like my shaders weren't compiling properly using `version 430 core`. Once I changed that to `version 330 core` it compiled! Many thanks for the help